# How to change the tooltip of jquery datepicker when changing to prev month?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

In jquery datepicker when we hover over the small triangle for selecting previous month. The tooltip shown is "Prev", i want the tooltip to be changed to "Previous".
How do i change the tooltip text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the text used for "previous" with the option `prevText`

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  prevText: "Previous"
});
```

[jQuery datepicker prevText](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-prevText)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#dateitem').datepicker({

    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    return [true, 'highlight', 'The custom title'];
    },
});
```